# passing parameters in functions

Tags: javascript

I have three functions

```
function function1(a,b){
   console.log(a,b)
}

function function2(a){
    function1(a)
}

function function3(b){
    function1(b)
}
```

But above is replacing b value with a in function1.But I need both values in function1.

Comment: do you have a use case for this? please add the call of the functions as well.

Comment: Yes im using function2 for getting changed page number in pagination  and function3 for search data.I need to pass both the data to service through function1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy solution could be the use of global variables, which hold the values for the wanted parts

- pagination
- search

and check the function which should return a search result.

```
function getSearch(p, s) {
    p = p || pagination;
    s = s || search;

    // perform searching
}

function setPagination(p) {
    pagination = p;
}

function setSearch(s) {
    search = s;
}

var pagination,
    search;
```

The function `getSearch` allows to call it in different ways:

```
//                                 taken  values  of
getSearch(undefined, undefined) // pagination search
getSearch()                     // pagination search
getSearch(undefined, 'text')    // pagination      s
getSearch(20, undefined)        // p          search
getSearch(20, 'text')           // p               s
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I need both values in function1.

You can pass those values as `undefined`

```
function function1(a,b){
   console.log(a,b)
}

function function2(a){
    function1(a); //b will already be passed as undefined
}

function function3(b){
    function1(undefined, b); //a is undefined
}
```

Comment: Using above i will get undfined in for parameter a in function1 while function3 is getting executed.But I need both values.

Comment: How can you have both values when you haven't passed `a` to `function3`, hence `a` is not in scope of `function3`? Only other way is to make `a` and `b` global and then you won't even need to pass those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
function function1(a,b){
   console.log(a,b)
}

function function2(a){
    function1(a); 
}

function function3(b){
    function1(null, b); 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion